# Checking if email has a response

Tags: sendgrid, mailgun

I have a SaaS product where a merchant sells services to customers and I want the merchant to have the ability to create email automation flows within my product.

An example of an automation would be

- A customer enquires about a service
- Automatic email sent
- Customer reads and doesn't respond within X days
- Another automatic email sent
- Customer responds and automation mode stops

So I was going to send these automated emails from my product domain with the reply to set the merchants email address

```
 From: auto@myproduct.com
 ReplyTo: bob@merchantsdomain.com,auto@myproduct.com
 To; customer@gmail.com
```

Is there an api within sendgrid or mailgun that facilitates the ability for my users to "bring there own inbox" and I can monitor email replies?

Comment: You want to know whether [sendgrid or mailgun has a particular feaure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746), right?